How to import fontforge in python3 with intellisense enabled in vscode on Ubuntu 22.04
I'm new to FontForge and I try several ways:

I install by sudo apt install fontforge python3-fontforge, I can import fontforge with the system python interpreter but without any intellisense, if I print(fontforge) it returns /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fontforge.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so, which I think it not possible to activate intellisense.

I build from source according to the INSTALL.md and I can run fontforge in bash, but I cannot import fontforge raises ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fontforge'  error. However in INSTALL.md, it said



libpython If present when FontForge is compiled, allows the user to execute python scripts within FontForge (and you can configure FontForge so that FontForge's functionality can be imported into python -- that is FontForge both extends and embeds python)

But I don't know how.
Can someone help me?
